# HTML - Outlook clients height issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

See the below code for a HTML email;

```
<table class="barcode" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:none !important; background:white; width:auto; margin: auto;">
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <!-- This is duplicated -->
    <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr>
            <td height="50" width="4.3" style="visibility:hidden; width:4.3px; height:50px; font-size:4px; color:#FFFFFF; color:transparent; padding: 0">&#9608;</td>
        </tr></table>
    </td>
    <!-- /This is duplicated -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `<td>` element in between the comments is duplicated multiple times (for barcode reasons). However, when you get past 100 (appx) `<td>` elements, Outlook clients seem to ignore the 50px `height`. Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

https://jsfiddle.net/uqtzov9u/1/ - Code that generated the above

I have tried removing the gross nested `table` and replaced it with a `div`, but still experience the same issue.

Why are Outlook clients ignoring the 50px `height` when I get past x number of `<td>` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all the inside tables, widths and kept only the outer td's and it works now in Outlook 2016 *Version 1802 (Build 9029.2167)*.

Now all you need is another set of td's that seperates the barcode lines with white.

```html
<table class="barcode" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:none !important; background:white; width:auto; margin: auto;">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">
   
   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
   <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;">

   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Recommendation: Dont use borders, use td with pixel width and give it a background color.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, Outlook likes tables to have a height and a width and will ignore styles.  Add `height="50"` to each table and the problem will be resolved.

```
<table height="50" class="barcode" border="2" style="border-collapse:collapse; border: none!important; background:white; width:auto; margin: auto; height: 50px!important;">
<tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td height="50" style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;"> 
    <table height="50" style="border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td height="50" width="4.3" style="visibility:hidden; width:4.3px; height:50px; font-size:4px; color:#FFFFFF; color:transparent; padding: 0">&#9608;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;"> 
    <table height="50" style="border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td height="50" width="2.3" style="visibility:hidden; width:2.3px; height:50px; font-size:2px; color:#FFFFFF; color:transparent; padding: 0">&#9608;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 50px; padding:0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0; background:white; border-width:0 0 0 1.6px; border-left-color: black; border-left-style: solid;"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately adding the height attribute to the tables doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: I tested this in Outlook 2013, 2016 and a range of other email clients because I wanted to figure out the answer. It didn't work for me until I added `height="50"` to each table.